# How do I implement a Player Interface for my game?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I have just implemented a player interface in order to make my program more object oriented. The game has a computer player and a human player, both of which implement from the player interface.

However, I cannot work out why the code isn't working. When running the program now, I am unable to input a counter onto the board and it only seems to be asking the human player to play (ignoring the computer logic).

Here is an image of the issue im experiencing:

[image]

**Player.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public interface Player {

    public String getUserInput() throws IOException;
    }
```

**HumanPlayer.Java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class HumanPlayer implements Player {

    @Override
    public String getUserInput() throws IOException {

        Board Connect4 = new Board();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        outer:
        while(true){

            int boardColumn = 0;

            //Player One Logic ----------------------------------------------------------------

            while(true){
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Player 1, please select your column:");
                boardColumn = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                if(Connect4.canMakeMove(boardColumn)){
                    if(Connect4.placeCounter(boardColumn, 1)){
                        Connect4.printBoard();
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! Player 1 has won the game");
                        break outer;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Column "+boardColumn+" is already full!!");
            }


    }
        return null;

    }   

}
```

**ComputerPlayer.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class ComputerPlayer implements Player{

    @Override
    public String getUserInput() throws IOException {

        Board Connect4 = new Board();

        outer:
        while(true){
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("The Computer has selected a column and played a counter");
            System.out.println("");

            Random r = new Random();
            int num = r.nextInt(7);

            int boardColumn = num;

            if(Connect4.canMakeMove(boardColumn)){
                if(Connect4.placeCounter(boardColumn, 2)){
                    Connect4.printBoard();
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("Unlucky! The Computer has won this game");
                    break outer;
                }
                break;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Column "+boardColumn+" is already full!!");
        }

        return null;
    }



}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

        Board Connect4 = new Board();


        welcomeMessage();
        Connect4.printBoard();


            HumanPlayer human = new HumanPlayer();
            human.getUserInput();

                Connect4.printBoard();

                //Player Two Logic ---------------------------------------------------------------   

                ComputerPlayer computer = new ComputerPlayer();
                computer.getUserInput();

                Connect4.printBoard();

            }


    public static void welcomeMessage() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Connect 4");
        System.out.println("There are 2 players red and yellow");
        System.out.println("Player 1 is Red, Player 2 is Yellow");
        System.out.println("To play the game type in the number of the boardColumn you want to drop you counter in");
        System.out.println("A player wins by connecting 4 counters in a row - vertically, horizontally or diagonally");
        System.out.println(""); 
    }
```

**Counter.java**

```
public abstract class Counter {

    int widthOfBoard = 7;
    int heightOfBoard = 7;
    int totalPlayed;
    int [][] gameBoard;

    public boolean placeCounter(int boardColumn, int playerNum){
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i<widthOfBoard; i++){
            if(gameBoard[i][boardColumn] == 1 || gameBoard[i][boardColumn] == 2){
                gameBoard[i-1][boardColumn]=playerNum;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == widthOfBoard)
            gameBoard[i-1][boardColumn]=playerNum;

        totalPlayed++;
        return isFourConnected(i-1,boardColumn);
    }

    public boolean canMakeMove(int boardColumn){
        return gameBoard[0][boardColumn] == 0; 
    }

    public boolean isFourConnected(int n1, int n2){
        int num=gameBoard[n1][n2];
        int count=0;
        int x = n2;

        // Vertical Logic ----------------------------------------------------
        count=0;
        int j=n1;
        while(j < widthOfBoard && gameBoard[j][n2] == num){
            count++;
            j++;
        }
        if(count == 4)
            return true;

        // Right Diagonal Logic ----------------------------------------------
        count=0;
        x = n1;
        j = n2;
        while(x< widthOfBoard && j < widthOfBoard && gameBoard[x][j] == num){
            count++;
            x++;
            j++;
        }

        if(count == 4)
            return true;

        // Left Diagonal Logic ------------------------------------------------
        count=0;
        x = n1;
        j = n2;
        while(x < widthOfBoard && j >= 0 && gameBoard[x][j] == num){
            count++;
            x++;
            j--;
        }

        if(count == 4)
            return true;

        // Horizontal Logic -------------------------------------------------
        while(x < widthOfBoard && gameBoard[n1][x] == num){
            count++;
            x++;
        }
        x = n2-1;
        while(x >= 0 && gameBoard[n1][x] == num){
            count++;
            x--;
        }
        if(count == 4)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Board.java**

```
public class Board extends Counter {

    public Board() {
        gameBoard = new int[super.heightOfBoard][super.widthOfBoard];
        super.totalPlayed = 0;
    }

    public void printBoard(){
        for(int i = 0; i<super.gameBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<super.gameBoard[0].length; j++){
                if(super.gameBoard[i][j] == 0)
                    System.out.print(".  ");
                else
                    System.out.print(super.gameBoard[i][j]+"  ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("0  1  2  3  4  5  6");
    }


}
```

Comment: *"Currently, I have a Human Interface, a HumanPlayer class and a ComputerPlayer class."* - Please, show them as well

Comment: Hi Andrew, first of all thank you for your reply. Human Interface, Human Player and ComputerPlayer currently have no code in them. I know that they need to exist for the purpose of an interface, however I just cannot work out how to organise my existing code from main into them

Comment: A player has an id, a name and can make a move. These are 3 methods for the `Player` interface

Comment: Thank you, good tip. But how would I implement say the random logic for ComputerPlayer into the move method?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what exactly you are having troubles with... You override a method in `ComputerPlayer` and copy the logic from `main` to it. Then you create an instance of `ComputerPlayer` and call the method on that object. You need to be specific to receive a good answer :)

Comment: Hi andrew, i have updated the question, i hope that is better?

Comment: `placeCounter` is a very bad name for a function which returns boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break outer;` drops you just before `while(true) loop` which keeps the `main thread` busy. Due to this reason, Your code is unable to execute past the line `human.getUserInput();` as it keeps on iterating until the breaking condition hits for `human.getUserInput();`